# Capistrano no longer working after removing rbenv

Tags: rvm, capistrano, rbenv

I removed RBENV and switched to RVM.

Now when i try to deploy with capistrano, or even try to just run "cap" i get:

```
/Users/me/.rbenv/shims/cap: No such file or directory
```

It's obviously still looking for the rbenv shim, but how do i get capistrano working on RVM?

I've tried removing and re-installing the gem, but that did not work...

Comment: Did you reload your terminal after removing rbenv?

Answer (score 0):

make sure `$PATH` is clear from `/Users/me/.rbenv`, then you can call `hash -r` to invalidate `PATH` cache.

also make sure you install gems again, both rbenv and rvm use custom paths for installing gems - so it's required to install gems again.